# How to parse this array from a ML result?

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, nlp, int64

How would one parse this print out? One would imagine it needs to assigned to a variable.

```
(array([[1., 1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1605, 1606, 1698, 1607]], dtype=int64))
```

For example, how would one parse 1605?

And/or, how would one parse 1605, 1606, 1698, 1607 from the second array?

This is a NLP result which is being worked with for the first time and your answer is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Ps. To clarify my question, this output is one of many NN NLP outputs to be parsed in a virtual environment, running in the API of an app. So, given this output, how would one parse only the second array, which are rows to be returned from a df? ie: One can not manually separate the arrays. Gervais' solution works in practice by manually typing in "np.", however this solution does not seem sustainable in a repetitive production environment, at least not by using string formatting. Any further insight into automating the parsing with out without numpy while the app is deployed would also be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most likely represent very different things, so I would personally separate them by performing a multiple assignment:

```
import numpy as np

x = (np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1.]]), 
     np.array([[1605, 1606, 1698, 1607]], dtype=np.int64))

a, b = x
```

Then you can access the first element of the second part with normal indexing:

```
b[0][0]
```

```
Out[9]: 1605
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very timely response and solution. The solution works great. However, since the initial code is an output from a neural net in an API intended to be running virtually (excuse me for not posting the entire NN script), do you have a good idea of how one could incorporate "np." into the functional result? I tried string formatting, and the code prints like your solution: "x = "({np}array([[1., 1., 1., 1.]]), {np}array([[1605, 1606, 1698, 1607]], dtype={np}int64))".format(np = 'np.')" However, when trying to parse x:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Oh I wouldn't know, unfortunately. I'm very sorry.

Comment: I just put the `np` to be able to reproduce your error, you might not even need it

Comment: No problem sir, still appreciated. The np is necessary. Thanks for showing us how to unpack this. In this shrouded NLP scenario the ML engineer was able to change the output to a json dump by using the model within a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1,1]], int)
b = np.array([[1605, 1606, 1698, 1607]], int)
c=[a,b]
d=np.vstack(c)
print('\n', c)
print('\n', d)
print('\n', d[1,0])
print('\n', d[1,2])
```

#output

```
 [array([[1, 1, 1, 1]]), array([[1605, 1606, 1698, 1607]])]

 [[   1    1    1    1]
 [1605 1606 1698 1607]]

 1605

 1698
```